# AWS S3 Copy performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Can anyone point me to some benchmark results for an S3 copy (cp) command for various size files up to 2GB?   I assume a copy is much quicker that a file upload for a similar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of the copy will very much depend upon your available network bandwidth. AWS has lots of network bandwidth, so the limitation would *not* be at that end.

If you are copying many files, the AWS CLI can copy files in parallel to take advantage of the full bandwidth available. You can also tweak some settings to optimize the copy process based upon typical file sizes.

See: [AWS CLI S3 Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)